# MySQL Workbench is adding --enable-cleartext-plugin option on mysqldump command

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-workbench

For some reason my copy of MySQL Workbench on one of my servers has started adding this **--enable-cleartext-plugin** option on every mysqldump command, which results in this error every time.

> 20:13:02 Dumping timesavr_dev (certifications) Running: mysqldump.exe
>   --defaults-file="c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\3\tmpn1an6u.cnf"  --set-gtid-purged=OFF --enable-cleartext-plugin --user=root --host=localhost --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers "timesavr_dev" mysqldump: unknown option '--enable-cleartext-plugin'
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 2 20:13:02 Export of
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TimeSavr\DB_Stuff\MySQLBackups\Dump20180608.sql has
>   finished with 1 errors

I just noticed this today but I suspect this started happening a few days ago when some other weird things also happened on this server.  After a reboot all the bindings on my website had disappeared, as had the user security privileges on the website folder, and for some reason Shared Config was enabled in my redirection.config file.  It all seems very random, and now this.

These are the options I have enabled, and I'm pretty sure these are default because when I click **Restore Defaults** nothing changes.

[image]

How can I tell MySQL Workbench to stop using the **--enable-cleartext-plugin** option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Enable Cleartext Authentication Plugin" is a connection setting, not a setting of "Data Export".

You can find it under "Database", "Manage Connections", here select your connection; inside the "Connection"-tab is the "Advanced"-tab with a checkbox to (un-)select that option.